# Modeling Biarticular Transmission Constraint in Gazebo

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I'm trying to simulate the [Meka T2 humanoid torso](http://mekabot.com/products/humanoid-torso/) that has a biarticular transmission joint constraint.  Specifically the robot's hip and thorax joints are connected by a cable that's controlled by a single motor ensuring that the two joints have the same angle.  How do I correctly model these types of joints in Gazebo and specify them in the SDF file?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/318/modeling-biarticular-transmission-constraint-in-gazebo/) by [liangfok](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/51/liangfok/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 21 on 2012-11-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I don't know of any way to express this type of constraint in SDF. Some constraint solvers are general enough to support this behavior, but gazebo does not expose that functionality.

As an alternative, I would model the two joints, and attempt to model the mechanical cable's stiffness and damping as a PD controller with the desired angle set as the current angle of the other joint. This can be done using a model plugin (see the [plugin tutorials](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.3/plugins) and the DiffDrivePlugin in [the gazebo plugins folder](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/dbae83d18e023d9532ba7961b3a3653931e85d03/plugins?at=default) for an example of the syntax).

---

Originally posted by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) with karma: 2861 on 2013-01-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0